# Find $p(2)$ of a polynomial $p$

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

> Let $p$ be a polynomial of fourth degree having extremum at $x=1$ and $x=2$ and
>   $\lim \limits_{x \to0}\left(1+\frac{p(x)}{x^2}\right)=2$. Then the value to $p(2)$ is?

This problem was in my book, I tried but I am not getting a clue as to how to begin.

Comment: Hint: If $P(x)/x^2$ has a limit as $x \rightarrow 0$, $P(x) = x^2q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ of second degree, i.e. $P(x) = x^2 \cdot (ax^2 + bx + c)$. Now try to use your conditions to solve for $a, b, c$.

Comment: That's fine to be learning mathjax and make a few mistakes here and there or have something be ambiguous so long as you are communicative about it and respond to clarification requests.  In case you haven't visited this post yet, [here is a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  We appreciate you trying and using it where you can.

Comment: thank you...I hope the question is clearer now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the limit exists if

$$\lim \limits_{x \to0} \frac{p(x)}{x^2}=1$$

and if $p(0)=0$, then by L'Hôpital

$$\lim \limits_{x \to0} \frac{p(x)}{x^2}=\lim \limits_{x \to0} \frac{p'(x)}{2x}=1$$

then $p'(0)=0$ and by L'Hôpital

$$\lim \limits_{x \to0} \frac{p'(x)}{2x}=\lim \limits_{x \to0} \frac{p''(x)}{2}=1\implies p''(0)=2$$

Moreover we know that $p'(1)=p'(2)=0$.

Then for $p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$ we deduce

- $p(0)=0 \implies e=0$
- $p'(0)=0 \implies d=0$
- $p''(0)=2 \implies 2c=2 \implies c=1 $

then $p(x)=ax^4+bx^3+x^2=0$ and now apply $p'(1)=0$ and $p'(2)=0$ that is

- $4a+3b+2=0$
- $32a+12b+4=0$

that is $a=\frac14$ and $b=-1$ then

$$p(x)=\frac14x^4-x^3+x^2$$

Answer (score 5):

You can write $p(x)=A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3+Ex^4$; compute the derivative and evaluate it at $1$ and $2$, where it should be $0$. Also
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{p(x)}{x^2}=1
$$
implies that $A=0$ and $B=0$ (why?), but also provides another condition.

In total you have five conditions that allow you to write the polynomial and compute its value at $2$.

Comment: can you explain why A=0 and B=0 I am having difficulty with this.

Comment: @IntegrateThis If either $A\ne0$ or $B\ne0$, the limit is not finite: you get $\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{A}{x^2}+\frac{B}{x}+C+Dx+Ex^2\right)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(x)=Ax^4 +Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E.$  Since $\lim_{x\to 0} 1+[P(x)/x^2]=2,$ we must have $E=0$ and $D=0$ and $C=1.$

So $P(x)=Ax^4+Bx^3+x^2.$

So $P'(x)=4A^3+3Bx^2+2x.$

Since $0=P'(1)=P'(2)$ we have $0=32A+12B+4=4A+3B+2,$ from which  $A$ and $B$ are found.

Comment: why E=-1? shouldn't it be zero

Comment: @DonAntonio   Arithmetic error. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

The finite limit implies $p=x^2+ax^3+bx^4$. The derivative $2x+3ax^2+4bx^3$ vanishes at $1$ and $2$, which gives simultaneous equations that obtain $a$ and $b$. Then $p(2)=4+8a+16b$ is trivial.